# Accessing ListViewItem.Tag from ItemClick handler

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

I am trying to attach a clicked item from a ListItemView.Tag to a type so I may use it in navigation. I am a bit confused how to attach the object.

```
private void ListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    this.Frame.Navigate(
        typeof(ListViewItem.Tag),
        e.ClickedItem,
        new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.DrillInNavigationTransitionInfo());
    }
```

Here is what my xaml looks like for this..

```
<ListView x:Name="ContentList"
          Grid.Row="1"
          Header="Select a group to view"
          EntranceNavigationTransitionInfo.IsTargetElement="True"
          IsItemClickEnabled="True"
          ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick"
          Margin="24,0,0,0">
    <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" Margin="12,4" Text="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
    <ListViewItem Content="Open Group" Tag="OpenGroup"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="Closed Group" Tag="ClosedGroup"/>
</ListView>
```

I basically want to generate `this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(OpenGroup));` from clicking the Open Group item and using the `Tag` to amend to my page name.

I want to do this for any item I add to the list for easy navigation modification.

Thanks

Comment: The Tag is Object ,not the type.

Comment: Type.GetType((sender as ListViewItem).Tag.ToString())

Comment: Thank you both for responding. I am still a bit lost here. It has been 10 years since I last really programmed, so I am kinda relearning here. I am trying to work with the suggestion, however, .tag is pulling a framework element and returning a null value. I am aware that it should be a framework element, however, there should be a value of OpenGroup or ClosedGroup, not null. I am also unsure how I would pass on the string as a type to the typeof() as typeof will not accept a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using simple `ListViewItems` you can't easily achieve your goal. In the `ItemClick` handler you have access only to the clicked "item" which is just the `string` value you have entered into the `Content` of the `ListViewItem` and not the `ListViewItem` itself. That means you have no access to the `Tag` either.

You will have to create a custom class that will **hold your "menu items"**:

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public MenuItem( string displayText, Type targetPage )
    {
        DisplayText = displayText;
        TargetPage = targetPage;
    }

    public string DisplayText { get; }

    public Type TargetPage { get; }
}
```

As you can see, I have already included a `Type` property to hold the page you will want to navigate to. Now in the **constructor** of your current **page** you will do this after `this.InitializeComponent();`:

```
ContentList.ItemsSource = new List<MenuItem>()
{
    new MenuItem( "Open Group", typeof( OpenGroupPage ) ),
    new MenuItem( "Closed Group", typeof( ClosedGroupPage ) ),
};
```

This way we have set the items as the source for the `ListView`. Now the control has some input, but does not know **how to display a `MenuItem`**. So we need to update it by adding a `ItemTemplate`:

```
<ListView x:Name="ContentList"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Header="Select a group to view"
        EntranceNavigationTransitionInfo.IsTargetElement="True"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick"                  
        Margin="24,0,0,0">
    <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" Margin="12,4" Text="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayText}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Note that the original `ListViewItem` elements should be **removed**, they are no longer needed.

Finally we will update the `ItemClick` handler to use the new `MenuItem` instances:

```
private void ListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{            
    var menuItem = e.ClickedItem as MenuItem;
    this.Frame.Navigate(
        menuItem.TargetPage,
        menuItem.DisplayText,
        new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.DrillInNavigationTransitionInfo());
}
```

Because the `ItemsSource` of the `ListView` is set to a list of `MenuItem`, the `ClickedItem` property now contains a `MenuItem` instance that was clicked. The `TargetPage` property is the page you navigate to and the `DisplayText` is the text that is displayed in the menu.

Comment: A different approach to doing exactly what I was trying to achieve, absolute rock solid. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> I basically want to generate this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(OpenGroup)); from clicking the Open Group item and using the Tag to amend to my page name.

Part agree with @Martin Zikmund, since you added `ListViewItem` with string content in your `ListView` directly in xaml, we can not access the `ListViewItem` in the `ItemClick` event, in order to access its `ListViewItem` and eventually access the `Tag` property when item is clicked, we can use `SelectionChanged` event instead of `ItemClick` event. For example:

```
<ListView x:Name="ContentList"
      Header="Select a group to view"
      EntranceNavigationTransitionInfo.IsTargetElement="True"
      SelectionMode="Single"
      SelectionChanged="ContentList_SelectionChanged"
      Margin="24,0,0,0">
    <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock  Margin="12,4" Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
    <ListViewItem Content="Open Group" Tag="OpenGroup"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="Closed Group" Tag="ClosedGroup"/>
</ListView>
```

> I am aware that it should be a framework element, however, there should be a value of OpenGroup or ClosedGroup, not null. I am also unsure how I would pass on the string as a type to the typeof() as typeof will not accept a string.

Then in the `SelectionChanged` event, it is important to get the type of your tag property. As you did, we can use `ToString()` method to convert the tag object to string, but if you get its type, it will return null. The key problem to this issue is that in UWP we need to build the namespace and this type string together, here is the sample:

```
private void ContentList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = e.AddedItems.FirstOrDefault() as ListViewItem; //single selection mode
    var type = Type.GetType("UWPControlsIssues4." + item.Tag.ToString()); //my project namespace is "UWPControlsIssues4"
    frame.Navigate(type);
}
```

I wrote this answer not saying Martin's answer is wrong, to do that you will need to build your data model and change a bunch of code, and normally we do this work in Martin's way. I think this answer is the method you were going to use.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. MUCH progress, however, type still passes null.. Frame.Navigate(type); throws a null exception. I can see the string item.tag propagated properly, however it is not attaching to type. This is the last hurdle I am facing on this part of my app lol.. My work around is so ugly.